# How to access other GCP services from Cloud Run

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to access Google Cloud Run from a Go website running within Cloud Run, but the program keeps panic-ing when I try to create the Vision Client:

`client, err := vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient(context.Background(), nil)`

Panic:

`runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine`

I assumed that as it's running within GCP and the Cloud Run service is assigned an IAM account with privilege to access Vision API it'd just be able to access it similar to Cloud Functions without a key, is there anything I'm missing here for it to work?

Comment: Your code and stack trace are too short! And it should work on your computer as in the cloud, no difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is quite short so it doesn't really give us enough information as to why it could be failing.

Looking at the documentation, I don't know that you need the `nil` as a second parameter to `vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient`.

[func NewImageAnnotatorClient](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1p1beta1#NewImageAnnotatorClient)

Try passing only the `context.Background()` and see if that fixes your issue.